# Problem in particles cache link

Tags: rendering, particles, cache

1. We made a car animation in blender - dust animation using blender’s smoke and baked the simulation in our network folder.
2. We can open the file from any computer, render it locally. Every thing is perfect.

BUT, when we copy and paste the .blend file, path of the cached simulation goes missing. But when we make copy using “Save As” option it’s good.

Can some one tell me how to solve this issue? I want blender to remember proper path “Relative” or “non relative”. Anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't make sense! If you move the blend file from one folder to another, and leave the cached sim where it is, you are changing the relative path, in this case it must be set using an absolute path. However, move both files at the same time, you are changing the absolute path and must use a relative path. The blend file doesn't remember where it was saved previously. There are several options under **File > External Data** to handle paths of external data. You can change them from absolute to relative and also find missing files.